# Where can I find the Apple CrashLanding example app?

Tags: iphone

Google returns me just nothing useful on these keywords. But I know there is a "CrashLanding" app demo from apple. Anyone knows where it is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Direct Download: http://www.71squared.co.uk/iPhone/CrashLanding.zip

It is from  a [tutorial on game programming](http://www.71squared.co.uk/2009/03/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-1/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 1):

That example was removed because its audio code was unstable.

Comment: who cares for audio ;) ... well i think for opengl that was nice.

Answer (score 1):

It's irritating that it's gone. I wish Apple would redo it properly and post it again. It's the best example of how to put an iPhone OPENGL ES game together that I've seen.

If you ask on boards like iDevGames, you might get some help finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has taken it off definitely. Maybe it's too old / bad practise. But for learning, may be better than to have nothing.

I found a blog where it is downloadable: [link text](http://www.71squared.co.uk/2009/03/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-1/comment-page-1/)